# Is uTorrent warning for nothing?

Tags: windows-xp, bittorrent, utorrent

The newest uTorrent version has a feature which warns me if the file is malicious.

I noticed that it was right at least once or twice, but after testing 4 different torrents I couldn't find any malicious files from the torrent (using Avast!), so I got suspicious: Is this just a monetizing trick from uTorrent? Since it is asking me to upgrade. The funny (or sad) thing is that when I press the upgrade button, it says I don't have internet connection and kind of bugs there (cant get back to torrents list anymore, unless I restart the program).

So what is going on... has someone hijacked uTorrent and is now trying to make money with it (but failing, hard), or what?! Should I change to some else torrent application?

Comment: Have you tried the latest version of BitTorrent?  You'd swear it was just a purple uTorrent.

Comment: @BonGart, what do you mean by the second sentence?

Comment: the chosen color in BitTorrent is purple, where in uTorrent it is green, otherwise the two programs appear to be identical.

Comment: uTorrent will waring any executeable file as malicious software.

Comment: @BonGart: [They are.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utorrent#Ownership_change)

Comment: they're based off the same codebase. I'm a little unhappy with the direction utorrent has taken with all the silly new addons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

uTorrent simply displays this for all file types, check the Do not show this again box and hide it.

P.S:-*It's a monetizing trick and it's what you can expect from the creators of modern era piracy*

Comment: have you tested it by making own torrent with non-malicious exes? or where did you get your information?

Comment: Yes, pissed when it did that for Fedora's ISO.

Comment: i think it displays it for exes only, or for isos too? at least not for avi etc video files.